# How do I read / understand the transparent color in a PNG image with imread?

Tags: python, image, numpy, colors, anaconda

This is my code (using Anaconda with scikit-image):

```
from skimage.io import imread
image = imread('myimage.png')
```

But I'd like to know which one, in the palette, is the transparent color, and be able to treat it like that. This means: When the image is finally loaded, it has shape `(W, H, 3)` as RGB, despite the info from `pnginfo` be the following:

> Bitdepth (Bits/Sample): 8
>   Channels (Samples/Pixel): 1
>   Pixel depth (Pixel Depth): 8
>   Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation): PALETTED COLOUR with alpha (44 colours, 1 transparent)

I would like one out of three:

- When loading the image, since I'm getting it as an RGB array, I would like to know which color (in this context I'd need the color as its RGB components) was intended to be transparent.
- Get a bit mask (actually a WxH boolean array) telling me which pixels are transparent and which pixels are non-transparent.
- Load the image as an RGBA array instead of an RGB array.

How can I?

I am using Anaconda, which has stuff like:

- Pillow
- Numpy
- SciPy

Comment: `imread` is a wrapper for python imaging library. Maybe it works if you pass the mode of the image as a named argument? `imread('myimage.png', mode='RGBA')`

Comment: The shape of the returned value of such execution still has `.shape == (H, W, 3)` instead of 4

Comment: You could try Pillow. `from PIL import Image; Image.open('myimage.png').split()` This should return the four channels RGBA.

Comment: Found a solution using other plugin. The `Image.open`-way would work if the image is already an RGBA.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it, in case someone else later has the same problem.

Comment: Yep I was writing it. I consider this problem a bug. I will report to the scikit-image project owners. Meanwhile, I fell back to a former function instead of the plugin-based approach: scipy.ndimage.imread (which does the trick of converting to alpha). `imread` should work as you told, but that only is true for scipy.ndimage.imread, but not for the pil plugin based imread.

Answer (score 0):

The `skimage.io.imread` method uses `Pillow` by default (since no plugin argument was passed, and Pillow is the first *preferred* plugin when calling functions like imread), but the plugin in `skimage.io.imread` does not make use of the `mode` argument as other plugins do. Part of the source code demonstrating this lack of support is this:

```
# This chunk of code belongs to the plugin implementation of imread.
im = Image.open(fname)
try:
    # this will raise an IOError if the file is not readable
    im.getdata()[0]
except IOError:
    site = "http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries"
    raise ValueError('Could not load "%s"\nPlease see documentation at: %s' % (fname, site))
else:
    return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)
```

Instead of calling `skimage.io.read`, there's one function in another package (`scipy.ndimage.imread`, which also comes if you have `scikit-image`) which does the needed trick:

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
rgba = imread('myimage.png', mode='RGBA')
```

Answer (score 0):

So scipy has depricated imread and python says to use matplotlib's plt.imread().
I had look around and found this example which creates a transparent image by removing the column defining the colour white
Code here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-background-image-transparent-using-python/

```
from PIL import Image
  
def convertImage(image=image):
    image = Image.open(image)
    image = image.convert("RGBA")
  
    data = image.getdata()
  
    newData = []
  
    for item in data:
        if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append(item)
  
    image.putdata(newData)
    image.save('newimage.png', "PNG")
    
#  
convertImage('apple.jpg')
```

As you can see it's not perfect but it depends on the resolution you need.
[Image of apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRmMT.png)